# Why did Dick Stensland laugh in this scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, la-confidential

During the night scene in *L.A Confidential* (1997), Officer Bud White and Dick Stensland are stationed in a
car outside a residence, observing as a man inside physically assaults
his spouse. In response to the situation, Bud White requests that the
central police station dispatch a patrol car, commonly known as a
“prowler,” to the specified address.:

> Bud White: Hollywood, this is 6-Adam-7. Have Central send a prowler
> to 4216 Evergreen. Parole violation. Assault arising from
> a family dispute. We won't be here, but they'll see him.

Then **Dick Stensland laughs** and Bud White gets out of the car.

Why did Dick Stensland laugh in this scene?

Comment: Because he knows what Bud is like and what he is likely to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Plainclothes officer Wendell "Bud" White is obsessed with punishing men who abuse women, his own mother having been beaten to death by his father. [L.A. Confidential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L.A._Confidential_(film)#Plot)

Dick laughs because he knows what will happen next: Bud will kick the man's ***. Because of his background, he won't (can't?) let this kind of things happen.